# Dialogflow Messenger CX intercept and add queryParams to responseBody

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I want to intercept the request from dialogflow messenger CX and add parameters to responseBody by queryParams, I have read the documentation but it is not clear about how to add the new parameters using javascript event. I understand that there is a event called `df-request-sent` but the documentation doesn't show about how to send the new parameters in the event. I have searched similar question but i didn't find information.

I am using the next documentation: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#df-request-sent

The code is:

```
         const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger')
         dfMessenger.addEventListener('df-request-sent', function (event) {
             console.log(event)
             // how to send the new parameters?
         })
```

I have tried changing the value of event.detail but it didn't work.

Anybody know how to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a super hacky way to do this, which is manipulating the user-id parameter in the df-messenger element. It is far from a best practice but it works for setting a string. ( I will share an approach in a while)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, adding parameters on the queryParams of the Dialogflow Messenger event’s df-request-sent isn’t possible. Please note that this event occurs when a request is made to the Dialogflow API, and we cannot edit the event structure as this is dependent on Dialogflow Messenger’s detectIntent request.

As a workaround, you can use custom integration. You can utilize Dialogflow CX’s [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview), [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3-overview), or [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc?hl=en) to create your own implementation/integration. Then, you can add parameters in your [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent?hl=en) request.

Here is a sample of detectIntent request body:

```
{
  "queryInput": {
     "text": {
        "text": "Hi"
     },
     "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "queryParams": {
     "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
     "parameters": {
         //set your parameters here
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [df-user-input-entered](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#df-user-input-entered), it's triggered once when the user presses send but before the request is sent:

```js
const dfMessenger = document.querySelector("df-messenger")
dfMessenger.addEventListener("df-user-input-entered", function(event) {
    dfMessenger.setQueryParameters('{"timeZone": "America/New_York"}');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'df-messenger-loaded' Event listener, it's triggered once when the messenger is loaded. You can use any Event Listener for it but setting **'parameters'** as JSON in **queryParams** is necessary.

```
 <script>
      document.addEventListener('df-messenger-loaded', function(event) {
        // Backend Would call this When user is Authorized 
        //Assuming df-messenger has been loaded
        const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
        const queryParams = {
          parameters:{"User_Authorized":"True","Information_Name":"Aymal Khan","Information_Email":"abc@gmail.com"}
        };
        dfMessenger.setQueryParameters(queryParams);
      });
    </script>
```